# Does "from" mean "born and raised in"?

Tags: grammar

To me, the two are often interchangeable, probably because people around me have talked to me in ways that have make it so.

Comment: In American English, it's context-dependent. If you're currently in the place where you live, then where you're "from" is indeed usually where you were raised (you might have been born somewhere else). If you're on vacation, or traveling for some reason, then where you're "from" is where you currently live.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that essentially the same question was asked in the past 6 months or so (but I'm too lazy to look it up).

Comment: Not specific enough - unclear. It can mean several different things, depending on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: I'm not sure if it's just personal to me but I always think of *born and raised* as being a specifically American expression. In England I always hear *'born and brought up'*. However I'll answer using your version.

In my opinion the difference shows up when when answering a question.

**1.**

"Where are you from?"

"Well currently I live in Scotland and have done so for twenty years but I was born and raised in England."

**2.**

"Where were you born and raised?"

"England."

Answer (score 2):

At least in the US, it can mean that, but it usually doesn't. In general, when someone says he (or she) is "from" somewhere, the meaning depends on context. If you were born and raised (roughly, through adolescence) in a town, you might say "Originally I'm from", regardless of the mismatch of tenses which occur.

But Americans move around a lot. For example, I was born in the state of Massachusetts, but our family moved to the state of Vermont when I was 5 years old, so I hardly remember much of my earliest childhood, and referred to myself as a Vermonter until I graduated from college and went to work in a different state.

Once you move to a new town, after quite a short period of time you refer to yourself as coming from your current community, especially when asked socially or by police officer, "Where are you from?". Such questions do not usually refer to your deepest sense of identity, and are not answered as if they do.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that "born and raised" has a more precise meaning. "From" could mean "born and raised", but it also has a more generic meaning, so you can say "born and raised" when you want to be unambiguous about your specific meaning.